# How to best track how long a video was played?

Tags: javascript, html, video

When the user watches a video, I would like to make 2 AJAX calls. One when the user finished watching the video and the time played is equal or more than the duration of the video (because users can rewind as well then). `timePlayed>=duration && event.type=="ended"`. I successfully make the call for that.

Where I struggle is that I would also like to make a call when the video is watched more than 80% and the time played of the video is more than 80% as well in order to prevent the user from just fast forwarding.

In order for that to work I have to modify my `videoStartedPlaying()` method and this is where I come across issues as I am trying to set an interval. Now, with setting an interval, it is like an endless loop.

```
var video_data = document.getElementById("video");

var timeStarted = -1;
var timePlayed = 0;
var duration = 0;

// If video metadata is loaded get duration
if(video_data.readyState > 0)
    getDuration.call(video_data);
//If metadata not loaded, use event to get it
else {
    video_data.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', getDuration);
}

// remember time user started the video
function videoStartedPlaying() {
    timeStarted = new Date().getTime()/1000;
    setInterval(function(){
        playedFor = new Date().getTime()/1000 - timeStarted;
        checkpoint = playedFor / duration;
        percentComplete = video_data.currentTime/video_data.duration;

        // here I need help of how to best accomplish this
        if (percentComplete >= 0.8 && checkpoint >= 0.8) {
            // AJAX call here
        }
    }, 2000);
}

function videoStoppedPlaying(event) {
    // Start time less then zero means stop event was fired vidout start event
    if(timeStarted>0) {
        var playedFor = new Date().getTime()/1000 - timeStarted;
        timeStarted = -1;
        // add the new amount of seconds played
        timePlayed+=playedFor;
    }

    // Count as complete only if end of video was reached
    if(timePlayed>=duration && event.type=="ended") {
        // AJAX call here
    }
}

function getDuration() {
    duration = video_data.duration;
}

video_data.addEventListener("play", videoStartedPlaying);
video_data.addEventListener("playing", videoStartedPlaying);
video_data.addEventListener("ended", videoStoppedPlaying);
video_data.addEventListener("pause", videoStoppedPlaying);
```

I truly would appreciate any help with this as it seems like I am at my wits end.

Thanks so much!

Edit:
Thanks to the comment I came up with this:

```js
const video = document.getElementById("video");
const set = new Set();
const percent = .8;
let toWatch;

function mediaWatched (curr) {
  alert(`${curr}% of media watched`)
}

function handleMetadata(e) {
  toWatch = Math.ceil(video.duration * percent);
  console.log(toWatch, video.duration);
}

function handleTimeupdate (e) {
  set.add(Math.ceil(video.currentTime));
  let watched = Array.from(set).pop();
  if (set.has(toWatch) && watched === toWatch) {
    video.removeEventListener("timeupdate", handleTimeupdate);
    console.log(watched);
    mediaWatched(
      Math.round(watched / Math.ceil(video.duration) * 100)
    );
  }
}

video.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", handleMetadata);

video.addEventListener("timeupdate", handleTimeupdate);
```

```html
<video width="400" height="300" controls="true" poster="" id="video">
    <source type="video/mp4" src="http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_2mb.mp4" />
</video>
```

Now, for example, if I fast forward to around 50% length, and let it play then, it will fire whenever 80% of the movie is reached, but it shouldn't because I fast forwarded to 50% and essentially only watched 30%.

Does that make sense? How can I achieve such behavior?

Comment: personally, I'd do this slightly differently... I'd decide on what granularity I wanted (eg 1 second) and create an array that holds as many slots as the video is long initialized to 0. I'd set an event on the video that triggers on `timeupdated` and set the slot (based off `currentTime`) in the array to '1'. When 80% of the slots are filled (from the start and/or total) then your logic can determine what they can do next...

Comment: oh, and for your code above, just set a flag once the ajax call is made and don't make it again, or remove the listener so it doesn't get called at all

Comment: @Offbeatmammal thanks for your comment! I came up with a slightly different approach thanks to you hinting to `timeupdated`. Now, the issue I have right now is that if I fast forward to around 50% length, and let it play then, it will fire whenever 80% of the movie is reached, but it shouldn't because I fast forwarded to 50% and essentially only watched 30%.

Does that make sense? How can I achieve such behavior?

Comment: that was why I suggested build the second by second (or whatever granularity you need) array ... that way if 80% of the entries are set to 1 rather than 0 then you know they've watched 80% of the available seconds...

Comment: Sorry for my rookie thinking haha. If I try a timer that counts for each second that was played a là `const timer = setInterval(() => {
  videoWatchedFor += 1; ... ` I run into the question of where I should put it in the code. If I place it into the `timeupdate` event, then the interval gets called 3-4 times a second. If I place it into the `play` event, it would still count even if the user pauses. Sorry about this, any hints are highly appreciated. This silly issue has taught me a lot already.

Comment: the problem with that approach is that if the user re-plays the same 5 seconds over and over again, rather than watching the whole 10 minutes then your counter will still increment. what I'm suggesting is mark your video off (via an array) into a number of chunks and using the `timeupdated` event on the video itself track which chunk is being watched and flag it. You can then use your timer to check the status of the array for >80% set to true and then make your ajax call

Comment: Thank you so much!! I finally completely understand what you meant and I have it figured out for the most part :-)

Comment: see answer for a working sample..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

per discussion in comments here's a working sample.

It includes a couple of handlers just to make life easier in setting up the array and summing the contents so you know when you have reached the 80% mark (though you may need to change that logic if you want to force them to, say, explicit watch the first 80% not just a total of 80% throughout the video).

There are a number of `console.log(...)` statements in there so you can watch what it's doing in the browser console window... you'll probably want to take them out before deploying for real.

I've put the hook for where to make the ajax call in the `timeupdate` event, but you could always use a regular `setInterval` timer in the main loop as well to check for the 80% and make the call there, but this seemed cleaner

most of it should be self explanatory, but do ask in comments if there's anything that's not clear...

```
<video controls preload="auto" id="video" width="640" height="365" muted>
      <source src="http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_2mb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>

<script>

 // handler to let me resize the array once we know the length
 Array.prototype.resize = function(newSize, defaultValue) {
    while(newSize > this.length)
        this.push(defaultValue);
    this.length = newSize;
}

// function to round up a number
function roundUp(num, precision) {
  return Math.ceil(num * precision) / precision
} 

var vid = document.getElementById("video")
var duration = 0; // will hold length of the video in seconds
var watched = new Array(0);
var reported80percent = false;

vid.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', getDuration, false);
vid.addEventListener('timeupdate',timeupdate,false)

function timeupdate() {
    currentTime = parseInt(vid.currentTime);
    // set the current second to "1" to flag it as watched
    watched[currentTime] = 1;

    // show the array of seconds so you can track what has been watched
    // you'll note that simply looping over the same few seconds never gets
    // the user closer to the magic 80%...
    console.log(watched);

    // sum the value of the array (add up the "watched" seconds)
    var sum = watched.reduce(function(acc, val) {return acc + val;}, 0);
    // take your desired action on the ?80% completion
    if ((sum >= (duration * .8)) && !reported80percent) {
        // set reported80percent to true so that the action is triggered once and only once
        // could also unregister the timeupdate event to avoid calling unneeded code at this point
        // vid.removeEventListener('timeupdate',timeupdate)
        reported80percent = true;
        console.log("80% watched...")
        // your ajax call to report progress could go here...   
    }
}

function getDuration() {
    console.log("duration:" + vid.duration)
    // get the duration in seconds, rounding up, to size the array
    duration = parseInt(roundUp(vid.duration,1));
    // resize the array, defaulting entries to zero
    console.log("resizing arrary to " + duration + " seconds.");
    watched.resize(duration,0)
}

</script>
```

Comment: Great answer!! That's much cleaner than what I had, essentially similar though, because of your tips! 2 quick questions: why is `vid.removeEventListener('timeupdate',timeupdate)` commented out? Wouldn't it make more sense to turn it off to save resources? Also, if the they video is 2 hours long, the array would have 7200 values. Would that approach still be a good approach?

Comment: :) I'd left the `removeEventListener` commented out because I wanted you to be able to see it continue to fill the array in if needed, absolutely remove the comments to make the code more efficient. an array of 7200 items shouldn't be a problem, fairly easy to test (didn't have a long video to hand so haven't confirmed yet)

Comment: Sounds good to me! Really appreciate it :-). I will test it, if it worst case gives issues, i can easily reduce it to every other second as well. Thanks so much! It took me 3 days to get to this point, with your help just within a few hours and then you put the icing on top by showing me a much cleaner example than what I had :-)

Comment: max theoretical size of an array is 4.29 billion elements with 'modern' browsers, so should be okay. just faked it with a four hour video and the performance seemed pretty much unimpacted (and memory footprint wasn't an issue) - Chrome, OSX for reference, YMMV