# HTML5 VIDEO tag how to restrict user for playing video only for 30 seconds

Tags: html, html5-video

I want user to play video only for few seconds

How can I record the seconds that user is playing the video

For Example

If a video was of 10 mints and i want to restrict the user to play only for 90 seconds where he can play any 90 seconds among the total video mints

How can this be possible using HTML5 video tag

Code

`<video width="320" id="myVid" height="240" controls>
  <source src="myVidClip.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>`

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42310019/how-to-best-track-how-long-a-video-was-played/42323463#42323463

Answer (score -1):

I've searching a bit and i searched you can play with CurrentTime attribute.

Read this : [CurrentTime Video Tag Attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video)