How to calculate the percentage of video watched
I am the proprietor of a website dedicated to improving user interactions by guaranteeing that users view a video from start to finish. In the event a user does not finish watching the video, I plan to display a label stating: "You've viewed 47% of this episode." My belief in its viability stems from witnessing its effectiveness on another website.
Despite employing all my known strategies and scouring the internet for solutions, I found no resolution. This serves as my final beacon of hope!

Looking at the number of close votes for this question you should consider adding an example of the code that you have so fare. Something that shows that the issue is.

the accepted answer below is okay for a simple check, but will be fooled by the user scrubbing straight to the end. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/42323463/1569675 for a more granular solution that breaks the video into a number of chunks and records how much of each chunk has been watched to get a more accurate read

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
            const video = document.getElementById('myVideo');
            const percentageWatched = document.getElementById('percentageWatched');

            video.addEventListener('timeupdate', () => {
                const watchedPercentage = (video.currentTime / video.duration) * 100;
                percentageWatched.innerHTML = `You've viewed ${watchedPercentage.toFixed(2)}% of this episode.`;
            });
        });


So appreciated O:-)
